# PHP Query Results with Barcode Image

Tags: php, arrays, header, barcode

I am trying to create a barcode for each of the results I get from my SQL Query.
Basically I have the results showing in an HTML table, and in the last column I want so show a barcode = to the value of $row=[1]. I am at a complete loss on how to do this.

```
<?php

//PHP Includes
include('inc/database.php');
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');
require_once('class/Barcode39.php');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

// MSSQL Query
$sql = "SELECT warehouse, pick_order_number, order_status, pick_order_type, customer_order_number
        FROM pick_order_header
        WHERE warehouse = 'XDGM'
        AND order_status <> 'Complete'
        AND order_status <> 'Closed'
        AND pick_order_type <> 'Backorder'";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
<html>
<title>Current Orders</title>
<body>

<table>
<?php
// SQLSRV Query
$results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $results === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
    echo "
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>Customer Order</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
            </tr>";
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $odrnum = $row[1];
        $odrstatus = $row[2];
        $odrtype = $row[3];
        $custorder = $row[4];
        $barcode = $row[1];

    echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$odrnum</td>
                <td>$odrstatus</td>
                <td>$odrtype</td>
                <td>$custorder</td>
                <td>$barcode</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To create the barcode I know I need to have

```
$code = new BCGcode39(); // Or another class name from the manual
$code->setScale(2); // Resolution
$code->setThickness(30); // Thickness
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black); // Color of bars
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white); // Color of spaces
$code->setFont($font); // Font (or 0)
$code->parse('HELLO'); // Text

$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $colorfg);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

Where I would like to see that barcode is

```
<td>$barcode</td>
```

I just have no clue on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem so straightforward as you approached it. I never used the library you're showing, I guess you're using http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/BCGcode39.

By the examples shown in that website, I figure the output from the `draw()` method is a bytestream corresponding to the image to be generated. There is a number of ways to accomplish what you want. One of them would be to have a process (some other file probably) which would receive the string and output the according barcode, and then call it inside your html table.

Something along the lines of:

1 - DrawBarcode.php

```
<?php
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $colorfg);
$drawing->setBarcode($_GET['code']);
$drawing->draw();
```

2 - Table.php

```
<?php   
// MSSQL Query
$sql = "SELECT warehouse, pick_order_number, order_status, pick_order_type, customer_order_number
        FROM pick_order_header
        WHERE warehouse = 'XDGM'
        AND order_status <> 'Complete'
        AND order_status <> 'Closed'
        AND pick_order_type <> 'Backorder'";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
<html>
<title>Current Orders</title>
<body>

<table>
<?php
// SQLSRV Query
$results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $results === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
    echo "
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>Customer Order</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
            </tr>";
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $odrnum = $row[1];
        $odrstatus = $row[2];
        $odrtype = $row[3];
        $custorder = $row[4];            

    echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$odrnum</td>
                <td>$odrstatus</td>
                <td>$odrtype</td>
                <td>$custorder</td>
                <td><img src="DrawBarcode.php?code=<?php echo $row[1];?>"/></td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

That should do it. Another way (very similar though), would be to generate the barcodes into files on your server, and then reference them as the source of the img tag.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I come to find out using this method exceed that memory allow as there is took much to draw. So now I am interested is saving files on the server then referencing them. Would you mind helping me with that scenario

Comment: If you read http://www.barcodephp.com/en/userguide you'll see that the first parameter to BCGDrawing::__construct is precisely a filename, so I suppose if you use that parameter, the draw method should leave the barcode inside that file and then you can simply use that file as img src. You should notice though that if that's all you change, you probably won't fix your memory problem. You should research some more into re-using the BCGDrawing object and also caching the images (In order not to generate the same image twice)